# Macbook Air cursor from trackpad freeze every 5 seconds

Tags: freeze, macbook, touchpad, cursor, macbook-air

Macbook air OS high Sierra (10.13.4 v).

The cursor from the trackpad freeze every 5 seconds, and when you click start moving again, but If you stop moving it, it will freeze again 5 seconds later.

Comment: A mouse pointer not moving is usually indicative of high system resource usage, not any specific problem with the mouse, TouchPad, or cursor itself. Please check for applications with spiking resource usage.

Comment: @music2myear I mean is like it were an option... because If I'm not using it in 5 seconds, then I can't move it, unless when I click